# Mid 2010 Macbook Pro goes into an unresponsive hibernate state for unpredictable amounts of time

Tags: sleep-wake, startup, hibernate

When my macbook is in standby, and the battery dies it sometimes goes into an unresponsive state in which (after charging) it won't turn on. The power button has no effect, even in combination with any key, such as T for target disk mode. The machine will stay in this state anywhere from a few hours to a few weeks and then spontaneously boot and resume from a hibernation state. (grey screen and loading bar) One one occasion, about 2.5 weeks had passed and the machine spontaneously woke up while it was being disassembled and scrapped for parts. Also, on at least three occasions, the computer just crashed (instant black screen) and the power button didn't turn it back on for a few days.

I'm running Mavericks 0.9.1 (13B42)
The special diagnostics self test (boot while holding d) does not report any errors.

If anyone has ideas of what to check, please share. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved by doing an SMC reset. press Shift-control-option-powerbutton when the machine is off and plugged in. The indicator on the magsafe adapter will flash from orange to green and back to orange.